# Who are the prisoners Thor convinces Steve Rogers to kill?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, team-thor

I've just seen the [Mocumentary](https://twitter.com/MarvelStudios/status/769927705651392513/video/1) 'Team Thor'.

While asking Darryl to write a letter,  Thor mentions convincing/coercing Steve Rogers to kill some prisoners and then says:

> if your have any more secrets you need kept,  let me know

When did that happen?

Comment: Maybe there were not any,  and it was just a joke.

Comment: Would answer, but Steve made me swear not to tell anyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It didn't......it's just part of Thor's desperate attempts to force Steve Rogers to contact him as he's not been invited into a side in Captain America: Civil War.

At least that's the way I took it.

Comment: The napping hammer was sooooo lovely...